# ValueError Input 0 of layer sequential_13 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4 Full shape received: (None, None, None, None)

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to work with a Simple RNN to predict Parkinson's Gait using Physionet Database. I am feeding the RNN with Images of height 240 and width of 16 pixels. I am also using Model checkpoint and monitor validation accuracy to save the best weights. While trying the input shape to the RNN I am getting that error as

```
 ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_13 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, None, None, None)
```

RNN model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(SimpleRNN(24, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', input_shape=(64,240), return_sequences = True))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

opt = optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001, decay=1e-6)
epoch=10
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', patience=60, verbose=1, mode='auto')
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("model_parkinsons.h5", 
                             monitor='val_accuracy', verbose=0, save_best_only=True, 
                             save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', save_freq='epoch')

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=opt,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Batch size:64

Height of the image: 240

```
a.shape
Output: (64, 16, 240, 1)
```

I tried to feed the input shape as a.shape[1:]

But I am getting the error as expected 3 dimension but got 4 dimension.

Please help me how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

In your first layer, you specified the input shape of your network. This shape does not include your batch size. So, if you specify "input_shape=(64, 240)", this would mean that your final input would need to have the shape (batch_size, 64, 240). Since 64 is your batch size, it seems like there definitely went something wrong there. Additionally, your input has four dimensions: (64, 16, 240, 1), but your first layer takes three dimensional inputs. I do not quite understand what you want to achieve with your model, but it should work if you input a[:, :, :, 0] into your model instead of a. Additionally, you need to set "input_shape=(16, 240)" in your first layer. If you do these two things, then your model uses the RNN to process one column of the image at a time. This approach does not make any sense to me (since RNNs are not used for image processing, at least not in this form), but I do not see any other way to interpret what you already did.